# Regex to find invalid characters in integer with whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, match

I want to use regular expression (regex) to find invalid characters in a string. The string is a user input and when the regex finds invalid characters I want to give the user feedback which characters where invalid. Example warning message: "Only 0-9 and whitespace allowed. Found invalid characters: ab" when input was `"- 10 a 0 b"`.

A valid string is:

- integer
- negative or positive
- is allowed to have any amount of whitespace at any position.

So for example those VALID strings should NOT match the regex:

```
"-100"  
"- 1 00"
"  - 1 00"
"100"  
" 1 0 0 "  
"1 00"
```

While the regex should find matches in these INVALID strings:

```
"- 1 a 0 0 b" should match "a" and "b"
"- 1 a 0 0 -" should match "a" and "-"
```

I had a working regex for positive integers, until i found out that I forgot to include negative integers:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9\s]")
var invalidCharacters = regex.Matches(text)
```

I have only very basic knowledge of regex. I tried out negating the regex to include negative integers, but it is not working:

```
new Regex(@"(?!-?[0-9\s])")
```

I hope someone can help me with this. If this can be solved easier by removing the whitespace requirement. Then please feel free to ignore the whitespace part.

Comment: Is `"   - 1"` valid (i.e. multiple spaces at the beginning before a `-` sign?

Comment: @Nick yes, multiple spaces at beginning before - sign is valid. I add this to the examples.

Comment: Why are `-100` and `100` invalid?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew they are valid

Comment: Instructions are unclear

Comment: Ok, your wording is not clear: *those strings should not match the regex*. What are you doing? Show more relevant code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i fixed that sentence, I hope it is more clear now

Comment: @MichaelRandall what part is unclear?

Comment: Are you validating or sanitizing a string? If validating, just use `Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\s*-?(?:\s*[0-9])+\s*$")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I validate the string and want to show a error message which tells the user which characters were invalid. For example: "only 0-9 and whitespace allowed. Found invalid characters: a, b". I dont want to clean the string.

Comment: Ok, use `var invalidCharacters = Regex.Matches(text, @"[^0-9\s-]|(?<!^\s*)-")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does not work with negative integers. I matches the "-"  when string is "-100".

Comment: No, [it does not](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e0-9%5cs-%5d%7c%28%3f%3c!%5e%5b%5ct%5cp%7bZs%7d%5d*%29-&i=-100%0d%0a-+1+00%0d%0a++-+1+00%0d%0a100%0d%0a+1+0+0+%0d%0a1+00%0d%0a%0d%0a-+1+a+0+0+b%0d%0a-+1+a+0+0+-&o=m). **Show me the code where it does.**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hm, strange. I check my code if something else is causing this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now it works. Thank you! I forgot that a second method was called as well which still had my old wrong regex. I have to refactor this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by thinking about the positive case first - which strings are valid? And then negate that with a negative lookaround.

I think this meets your requirements:

```
(?!\s*-?[\d\s]).
```

- `\s*` will match any whitespace at the start
- `-?` will optionally match a hyphen
- `[\d\s]` will match numbers and whitespace
- `(?!expression)` is a negative lookaround to negate the whole expression
- The `.` at the end is a way to generate matches. The negative lookaround is just an assertion - it doesn't return any results.

It produces the desired results for the test cases in your question.

Comment: what is the `.` at the end for?

Comment: The negative lookaround is just an assertion. The `.` allows the regex to materialise the results.

Comment: ok, thanks. Both answers are working well. I will accept this one, because I find the regex easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
var invalidCharacters = Regex.Matches(text, @"[^0-9\s-]|(?<!^\s*)-");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e0-9%5cs-%5d%7c%28%3f%3c!%5e%5b%5cs-%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%5d*%29-&i=-100%0d%0a-+1+00%0d%0a++-+1+00%0d%0a100%0d%0a+1+0+0+%0d%0a1+00%0d%0a%0d%0a-+1+a+0+0+b%0d%0a-+1+a+0+0+-&o=m) (modified a bit as the demo is a test against a single multiline string.)

The regex matches:

- `[^0-9\s-]` - a char other than an ASCII digit, any Unicode whitespace char or a `-` char
- `|` - or
- `(?<!^\s*)-` - a `-` char that is not preceded with the start of string any any 0+ whitespace chars.